# Using a weapon to execute a combat maneuver

Tags: pathfinder-1e, ranged-attack, combat-maneuver

My character is a Marksman [Finesse Style](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/classes/marksman/marksman-combat-styles#TOC-Finesse-Style), and has the ability to use her ranged weapon to execute a combat maneuver.

> Once a Marksman has reached 2nd level, she may expend her psionic
>   focus while making a ranged attack to use one of the following combat
>   maneuvers as a ranged attack: bull rush, dirty trick, disarm, sunder,
>   or trip. The Marksman may use either her Strength or Dexterity
>   modifier when determining her CMB for this attack. The ranged attack
>   deals no damage and provokes attacks of opportunity as normal.

My weapon has a plus 5 to hit (before dexterity). Does that factor into my CMB at all? I can understand doing a CMB without a weapon would not gain a weapon's attack bonuses, but it makes sense to me that using a weapon to do a CMB would be influenced by the weapon itself. I want to make sure I'm using this correctly, because it can make or break a situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you use the +5 to hit.

[CMB Explained](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Combat-Maneuver-Bonus)

> When you attempt to perform a combat maneuver, make an attack roll and add your CMB in place of your normal attack bonus. Add any bonuses you currently have on attack rolls due to spells, feats, and other effects. These bonuses must be applicable to the weapon or attack used to perform the maneuver.

As the +5 to hit is a bonus you currently have on attack rolls that are applicable to the weapon / attack, you would use that when determining your CMB.